# Magento 2 : Upgrade Magento 2.3 to 2.4

Tags: magento2, upgrade

I have upgraded `Magento 2.3 to 2.4`.

I have also upgraded the older version of  3rd party modules to newer versions.

There may be design changes in newer versions of modules. (i.e in template, CSS & js files)

Question - I am not sure how to check for these new changes in 3rd party modules & apply those changes in a custom theme.

Any thoughts on this?

Comment: Any thoughts on this ?

Comment: This is something manually work you need to do here.

Comment: yes but how it can be done ?
I mean checking all custom theme files and update files if same file in core is updated
?

Comment: not theme file you need ot check third party extension frontend files only where may be affected.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, you mean comparing the latest template & other files from latest  third party extension with same old modules Frontend files ?

Comment: try to use phpcs-fixed , phpstan and rector. These feature will upgrade some code automatically and also will suggest manual up-gradation i code.

Rector -  https://github.com/rectorphp/rector
phpstan -  https://github.com/phpstan/phpstan
phpcs-fixer -  https://github.com/FriendsOfPHP/PHP-CS-Fixer

Comment: Thankyou very much @SameerBhayani for the comment, these tools appears helpfull.
Though need to check how to use it thoughout magento project (i,e magento setup).
Would you like to add information how to make it use in magento ?

Comment: This will help you throughout project. @magedev

Answer (score 1):

Here you have following way.

1. Test the whole magento frontend, and if you found any issues on any screen then debug is that any error from that third party extension and make them compatible same like older.
2. In another way, you can compare the third party frontend files, is there any changes compare to old one, if yes then do that one.

Comment: Thankyou very much for the answer.

Comment: Testing the magento Frontend is bit difficult for now as it lacks the images.
Can i add images to pub/media for such path https://website/media/wysiwyg/promo1.png
to fix issues with images ?

Comment: yes you can copy the images on particular location from old one.

Comment: I may need to check for layout & js files also right along with template files ?
What are your thoughts on this ?

Comment: main thing is check site functionality work as before or not.. check frontend design too.. if anything not as before then fix that thing.. you need to check whole site no another way to make site stable as before

Comment: Great thanks for the advice @GohilRajesh

Comment: In another way, you can compare the third party frontend files, is there any changes compare to old one, if yes then do that one.

The comparison should be done for ( latest third party frontend files with files which are override in theme )
& add changes if found in that theme file itself.

Comment: yes, exactly...